# Can't print text inside 'p' tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Pretty simple code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.birdsnest.com.au/brands/boho-bird/73067-amore-wrap-dress'
page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
page_new = soup.find('div', class_='model-info clearfix')
results = page_new.find_all('p')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

Output

```
usually wears a size .
                She is wearing a size  in this style.
              
Her height is .

Show ’s body measurements
```

The problem is that the model's name is inside `<strong>` tags and a `span` inside the `<strong>` tag.
Like so.

```html
<div class="model-info-header">
              <p>
                <strong><span class="model-info__name">Marnee</span></strong> usually wears a size <strong><span class="model-info__standard-size">8</span></strong>.
                She is wearing a size <strong><span class="model-info__wears-size">10</span></strong> in this style.
              </p>
              <p class="model-info-header__height">Her height is <strong><span class="model-info__height">178 cm</span></strong>.</p>
              <p>
                <span class="js-model-info-more model-info__link model-info-header__more">Show <span class="model-info__name">Marnee</span>’s body measurements</span>
              </p>
            </div>
```

How to get the BOLD elements inside the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model name is generated dynamically. Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

link = 'https://www.birdsnest.com.au/brands/boho-bird/73067-amore-wrap-dress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.close()
page_new = soup.find('div', class_='model-info clearfix')
results = page_new.find_all('p')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```

Output:

```
Marnee usually wears a size 8.
                She is wearing a size 10 in this style.
              
Her height is 178 cm.
Show Marnee’s body measurements
Marnee’s body measurements are:
Bust 81 cm
Waist 64 cm
Hips 89 cm
```

Comment: Do I have to use selenium? Can't this be done with requests?

Comment: The model name is not present in the `p` tag when u do `requests.get`. This means that it is loaded dynamically. So u have to use `selenium`. No other go.